# Missing triangles on 3D sphere with Libgdx

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx

I'm trying to build a 3d transparent globe on android (with transparent regions at the place of water regions) and the way I'm doing it is by creating a sphere model with Libgdx and then filling it with a .png texture of the earth with transparent water regions. It is working fine except that after I disable cull face (to be able to see the back face of the sphere), I observe some triangles missing and the back face vanishes as I rotate the 3d model: [Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iQjY.jpg), [Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7csEH.jpg). If I rotate the sphere at some other angles it appairs to work fine and I can see without problem the back face of the globe.

I put here some relevant code:

render:

```
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    camController.update();
    modelBatch.begin(cam);      
    modelBatch.render(instance, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
```

I've tried all possible values for the DepthTestAttribute but seems that there is no way to get rid of this very strange effect. Please give me some advice, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried disabling depth testing?

Comment: Yes, but i get some weird result where the missing triangles are not on the back but on the front. And they are filled not with transparency but with the back part of the sphere... it's something really strange

Comment: Do you sort the triangles from back to front before rendering?

Comment: All I'm doing is written on the code that I posted... I don't know how to sort them.. can you give me a hint? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of general geometry, one common approach is to sort the triangles, and render them in back to front order.

However, with the special properties of a sphere, I believe there is a simpler and more efficient approach that should work well. With a sphere, you always have exactly one layer of back-facing triangles and exactly one layer of front-facing triangles. So if you render the back-facing triangles first, followed by the front-facing triangles, you get an order where a triangle rendered earlier is never in front of a triangle rendered later, which is sufficient to get correct transparency rendering.

You already figured out how to render only the front-facing triangles: By enabling culling of the back faces. Rendering only the back-facing triangles is the same thing, except that you call the front faces. So the code looks like this:

```
glBlendFunc(...);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

glClear(...);

glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
// draw sphere

glCullFace(GL_BACK);
// draw sphere
```

Comment: Sir, I want to kiss you right now. That was simply genial. It's the classic situation when there is a many days problem and than someone comes and in two words solves it. Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the typical conflict between transparency and depth testing.

A transparent pixel is drawn, but does write a value to the depth buffer causing pixels behind it - which are supposed to be visible - to be discarded due to a failed depth test.

Same happens here. Some elements in front are drawn first - writing to the depth buffer even though parts are translucent - so elements behind it are not drawn.

A quick and dirty fix would be to discard pixels with an alpha value below a certain threshold by enabling alpha testing (or discarding it in your shader in later OpenGL versions). However, this will in most cases result in visible artifacts.

A better way would be to sort the individual elements/triangles of the globe from back to front relative to the camera and drawing them in that order.

I would also suggest you read the OpenGL wiki on https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting